# limit std::vector for given min and max values

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I've a `std::vector` of `double` values and I'm searching for a way to limit the sorted result to certain min and max values. Let me provide an example -

```
std::vector<double> v;
v.push_back(2.5);
v.push_back(3.5);
v.push_back(4.5);
v.push_back(5.5);
v.push_back(6.5);
```

In above example, if I execute `limit(v, 4.0, 7.0);` it should provide me indexes eg `[2]` to `[4]` or end or whatever. I tried searching for `<algorithm>` header but couldn't find one :/ I can use additional library too if the need arises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) and [`std::upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound):

```
auto it1 = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 4.0);
auto it2 = std::upper_bound(it1, v.end(), 7.0);

for (auto it = it1; it != it2; ++it)
    std::cout << *it << "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks, I also tried searching for a 5-10 minutes, didn't know it's name so I posted the question. I'll accept after 8 mins.

Answer (score 1):

Kerrek SB's solution is great but implies that `v` is sorted.  If it is not sorted, use [`std::partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<double> v = { 4.5, 2.5, 5.5, 6.5, 3.5 };

  auto part = std::partition(v.begin(), v.end(), [](double d){return 4 < d && d < 7;});

  for (auto it = std::begin(v); it != part; ++it)
    std::cout << *it << "\n";
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/YGuWQQ)

Comment: What would be the complexity difference if I chose this against sorting and then applying upper and lower bound?

Comment: ah okay, it makes changes to original container so it's not exactly similar. Good answer but in my case it won't work since my container is already sorted and I don't want change to original container.

Comment: @LaserFocus Sort is usually O(N log N) and `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` are logarithmic in the distance to the element.  Partitioning is O(N log N) but I'm not sure.  The description is a little confusing.